# How to edit this loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I have written a small piece of code which doesn´t work like I want.
My goals:

I have a textbox with 3 lines. Each line = one product.
I have a second textbox with 2 lines. Each line = 1 variant of a product.

My result should be something like this:

> Artificial grass | Red
>
> Artificial grass.1 | Blue
>
> Dark hole plate | Red
>
> Dark hole plate.1 | Blue
>
> Test hole plate | Red
>
> Test hole plate.1 | Blue

I have this code (deleted all the unneccessary parameters for you):

```
For value1 As Integer = 0 To NumberOfArticles - 1           
    Dim Name As String = ProductTB.Lines(value1)              
    Dim Variants As String = VariantsTB.Lines(value1)

    For value2 As Integer = 1 To VariantsCountTB.Text - 1    'TextBox with number of variants                                  
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() { VariantsTB.Lines(value2 - 1)}) 
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {VariantsTB.Lines(value2)}) 
    Next

    If value1 = NumberOfArticles Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Name is each line of the product textbox.
Variants is each line of the variants TextBox.

The problem: It works, but ONLY if there are as many variants as products. But I need for example only 2 variants, but 3 products. So, where to edit this loop?

Thank you very much! :)

Best regards

Comment: First things first, don't be using the `Lines` property over and over like that. That property is not "live", i.e. it doesn't correspond to some existent data in the control. It has to construct an array every time you get the property value. As such, you should be getting each `Lines` property once only, at the start of the code. You should be assigning those arrays to variables and then using those variables repeatedly, so using the same arrays repeatedly.

Comment: As for the issue, you haven't done enough work for yourself yet. The course of events is not you running the code, it not working so you asking a question. You need to actually debug the code first. You need to set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step. You need to know EXACTLY what you expect to happen before each step and you can test that it did happen after each step. As soon as reality differs from expectation, you have isolated an issue. Even if you can't fix it, at least you can provide us with more relevant information.

Comment: If the reality never actually differs from your expectations then it's your expectations that are wrong, so you need to reevaluate them. You should go back and write an actual algorithm, test it manually until you're sure that it works, then write code to implement that algorithm specifically

Comment: I have deleted my answer as @jmcilhinney's comments are much more valuable for you

Answer (score 0):

As jmcilhinney mentioned use `lines()` to save textbox text in a array and then do the looping on the same

```
''Get all Products in array
Dim products As String() = ProductTB.Lines()
''Get all attributes in array
Dim attrributes As String() = VariantsTB.Lines()
''Create as list for result
Dim resultlist As New List(Of String)

''Loop over product
For Each prod As String In products

    ''Loop over Attributes
    For Each atr As String In attrributes
        Dim resultprd = prod & "|" & atr
        resultlist.Add(resultprd)
    Next

    '' if you want proiducts without attributes also add here 
    ''resultlist.Add("Prod")
Next
```